# Why does my Kafka consumer poll so quickly?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

My Kafka consumer is polling more quickly than I would expect. Is there some config I can change to make it wait the whole time in `fetch.max.wait.ms`?

I set the fetch.max.wait.ms to some number of seconds (5). I set `fetch.min.bytes` to some large number of bytes (99,988,800).

I read the documentation (but may have missed something):

> https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/
>
> - fetch.min.bytes
> - The minimum amount of data the server should return for a fetch request. If insufficient data is available the request will wait for that much data to accumulate before answering the request. The default setting of 1 byte means that fetch requests are answered as soon as a single byte of data is available or the fetch request times out waiting for data to arrive. Setting this to something greater than 1 will cause the server to wait for larger amounts of data to accumulate which can improve server throughput a bit at the cost of some additional latency.
> - fetch.max.wait.ms
> - The maximum amount of time the server will block before answering the fetch request if there isn't sufficient data to immediately satisfy the requirement given by fetch.min.bytes.

```
fetch.max.wait.ms=5000,
fetch.min.bytes=99988800
```

Based on my configuration options and data set, I expect the call to `poll` to always block for 5 seconds before returning any records.

Instead, the call to `poll` sometimes resolves in less than a second and always has some small number records.

Here is the output of a sample run:

```
// send 100 records
// doesn't matter how

// timestamp -> records received
// (date, hour and minute are not shown, just the relevant seconds.millis)

32.475 -> 10
33.392 -> 12
34.116 -> 16
37.477 -> 16
38.395 -> 18
39.118 -> 17
42.479 -> 7
43.397 -> 4
```

No delay was really close to 5s.

Comment: I'm not sure, we're using this, and it works for us. So I'd make sure, if your setting are picked at all in first place?
private Map<String, Object> jsonConsumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 200);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, 10000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, 2147483647);
        return props;
    }

Comment: @xerige2 were you able to get this to work for spring-kafka? Also Martin that config is set for spring-kafka or the kafka consumer class?

Answer (score 5):

With property `fetch.max.wait.ms=5000` you said: "Don't wait more than 5 seconds even if there is not enough data to pick up". You didn't specified minimum amount of seconds before you execute poll. You can test this behavior by starting 2 kafka consumers and in one of them you set `fetch.max.wait.ms=20000` and in the other one left default value. You will see that in consumer with default settings you will receive messages almost immediately and in consumer with `fetch.max.wait.ms=20000` you will have to wait a little bit. I tried it on my machine with setting `fetch.max.wait.ms=20000` and sometimes it takes 15 seconds to receive record, sometimes 10 seconds etc. but never more than 20 seconds passed.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to adjust max.partition.fetch.bytes, message.max.bytes and max.message.bytes.
If the size of each record is about 100KB, 10 records will trigger the delivery. This might be what you saw in your case.